# Filtering objects in Django based on optional arguments

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Many times I find myself writing code similar to:

```
query = MyModel.objects.all()
if request.GET.get('filter_by_field1'):
    query = query.filter(field1 = True)
if request.GET.get('filter_by_field2'):
    query = query.filter(field2 = False)
field3_filter = request.GET.get('field3'):
if field3_filter is not None:
    query = query.filter(field3 = field3_filter)
if field4_filter:
    query = query.filter(field4 = field4_filter)
# etc...
return query
```

Is there a better, more generic way of building queries such as the one above?

Answer (score 3):

If the only things that are ever going to be in request GET are potential query arguments, you could do this:

```
query = MyModel.objects.filter(**request.GET)
```

Comment: This makes sense. Two concerns: (1) not all arguments come from `request.GET` (just edited the question to reflect that) and (2) I don't want to allow filtering on every field.

Comment: Well, you can build up a dictionary with a combination of arguments from request and elsewhere, and sanitise where necessary; the theory is the same.